# HTML5 video space on Safari?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, safari

I have a HTML5 video that is the background for my header.
The video dimensions is 1280 x 720. But in safari their is space on the top and bottom of the HTML5 video. This space only shows on safari on a Mac OS X, This displays fine on Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Edge. I have tried adding `display: block` and many other values for `display` but have not worked. Also if I go into Inspect Element and turn off the `display` then turn it back on it will start working again.

Also to mention this site is a custom theme for WordPress.

**MY CODE:**

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="home-banner">

        <div class="fullscreen-bg clearfix">

            <!-- Video -->

            <video class="hidden-xs" loop autoplay muted poster="images/videoframe.jpg">

                <source src="video/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">

            </video>

        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
video {
    /*float: left;*/
    width: 100%;
}
.fullscreen-bg {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.fullscreen-bg .container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1111;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 85% !important;
}
.home-banner {
    /*background-image: url(../images/home-banner.jpg);*/
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Is their any update on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I just used:

```
video {
    /*float: left;*/
    min-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```